# I can't install db-mysql in node.js

Tags: mysql, windows

When I execute this command: `npm install db-mysql`, I get the following result.  What's the solution to this problem?

```
C:\Users\Mouad>npm install db-mysql
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql
npm ERR! Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1283:32)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:896:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:430:15)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:294:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:344:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:211:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:201:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:172:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:547:24)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http: //github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     "npm-@googlegroups.com"

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-> cli.js" "install" "db-mysql"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Mouad
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mouad\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? Edit: I'm guessing Windows?

Comment: yes i use windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change config to allow `SELF_SIGNED_CERT`

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

or change registry url to http:// one

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

Comment: thanx but i have other erreur :


C:\Users\Mouad>npm install db-mysql
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql

    db-mysql@0.7.6 install C:\Users\Mouad\node_modules\db-mysql
    node-waf configure build

'node-waf' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

    db-mysql@0.7.6 preuninstall C:\Users\Mouad\node_modules\db-mysql
    rm -rf build/*

'rm' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes...